# Exchange Web Services vrs WebDAV

Tags: webdav, exchangewebservices

What are some good resources for learning Exchange Web Services?

I'm familiar with WebDAV and was wondering if exchange web services might be better for some integration we do with Exchange.

Comment: I believe webdav is deprecated in the newer Exchange releases as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i wrote a wrapper library for exchange 2007 some weeks ago.

i found greg's blog pretty good. 
http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/index.html

then i also found the following codeproject article extremely helpful.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exchange/Exchange2007EWS-Part1.aspx

good luck

Comment: I think you meant Glen's blog :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a book on the subject from David Sterling called [Inside Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 Web Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623929).

[Book Cover http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51TFbqF1CrL._SL75_.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51TFbqF1CrL._SL75_.jpg)

I have found it very useful in learning about Exchange Web Services (a.k.a. EWS).

Recently, Microsoft released the client counter part of EWS dubbed EWS Managed API. It offers a much friendlier API than those generated through Visual Studio proxy class generators.
It can be downloaded at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=c3342fb3-fbcc-4127-becf-872c746840e1 and documentation can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633709(EXCHG.80).aspx

Unfortunately the aforementioned book does not cover EWS Managed API since the API was released after the book.

A few blogs I found useful while researching about Exchange stuff:

- [Dan's WebDAV 101](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdav_101/default.aspx)
- [Exchange API-spotting](http://blogs.msdn.com/exchangedev/default.aspx)
- [mstehle: The CDOs and CDONTS of Messaging Development](http://blogs.msdn.com/mstehle/default.aspx)
- [SGriffin's MAPI Internals](http://blogs.msdn.com/stephen_griffin/default.aspx)
- [Jive into Messaging world](http://blogs.msdn.com/vikas/default.aspx)
- [You Had Me At EHLO](http://msexchangeteam.com/default.aspx)

Although most of them are not specifically devoted to EWS I’ve found interesting pieces of information some way or another useful for dealing with EWS in all of them.